# Autofill formula for cell names in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, drag, autofill, names

In an Excel worksheet with rows of parameters and columns of systems like so:

```
        system1 system2
height    58      65
width     12      17
weight     3       5
 ...       .       .
 ...       .       .
```

I am looking for a way to use this data with meaningful names such as "height1", "height2".
I can name the cells "height1" "height2" (Formulas->Define Name) and use it in a cell =height1.
However, when autofilling by dragging the equation to the right, the name does not change to height2 and I am left with the same value of 58.

Basically, I am looking for the same behavior as autofill dragging =B2 to =B3, but with meaningful names.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro for naming them all in your convention (haven't tried it but should work):

```
Sub NameThem()
    Dim rng As Range
    For i = 0 To 3
        For j = 0 To 1
            Set rng = Range("A1").Offset(1 + i, 1 + j)
            Call ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add(rng.End(xlToLeft).Value & j, rng)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Although your script may be handy, naming the cells is the easier task - it will only be done once.
Autofilling equations is much harder, because equations can be very long (up to 8 parameters), and changed often. Each change will have to be applied for all systems.

Right now, where all equations point to regular col/row convention, it is easy to apply an equation change to all 10 systems (just autofill drag the edited equation to the right).

Comment: Do you mean that based on this you want to updated the references with names? E.g. say B2 is named height1 then you want to updated all references to B2 with height1?

Comment: Let me try to rephrase. I have a table of inputs and a similarly sized table of equations. I want to enter the first column of equations (for system1) and then drag autofill those equations to columns system2, system3 etc..
This is easily done when using =b2 (for example dragging the equation =b3*b5 to the right, will autofill to =c3*c5) but is not workig with names (dragging =height1*width1 autofills =height1*width1).